Seleniumbase chromdriver: Crash or blocked on target load
Since today my seleniumbase script has stopped to work.
When I load a page which has only JSON contents, the webdriver still working, but when I load a page with a "regular" webpage (HTML, CSS, etc.) the webdriver suddenly keeps "freeze".
The configuration is the following one:
# !/bin/bash/python3
from seleniumbase import Driver
driver = Driver(uc = True, proxy = proxy_string)
# some code
driver.get(url)
driver.get(page_source)

The page get freeze and not crash or doing anything.
I'm using the Chromdriver version: 126.0.6478.62 and I just update to seleniumbase==4.29
Load page with seleniumbase webdriver

Finally the answer was updating to Seleniumbase==4.29 and also update Java Version to the latest.

Not an answer. Update it in the comment section.
